# Template Tool kit - Subtract days from a given date in the template

Tags: perl, template-engine

First, I don't have access to the code I have to try to do this on the template.

I have a date that will be available on the template [%UserDate%]

I need to subtract 120 days from the provided [%UserDate%] value.

```
<div>
120 Days Before:  [%UserDate%]
</div>
```

I tried to find a way to to this here:
http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Date.html
and here:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Calc

But either I am lost or can not find a method or way to do it.

Comment: What does UserDate actually contain? A string? An epoch time? An object of some sort, and if so what sort?

Comment: 05/12/2023 a date in that format.

Comment: TT offers possibilities to embed perl code: http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_PERL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a) that `UserDate` is just a string and nothing useful like a [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) object and b) that you have [Date::Calc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Calc) installed, then this seems to get you most of the way there:

```
[% UserDate = '05/12/2023' -%]
[% UserDateArray = UserDate.split('/') -%]
[% USE date -%]
Original date: [% UserDate %]
120 days before: [% date.calc.Add_Delta_Days(UserDateArray.2,
                                             UserDateArray.1,
                                             UserDateArray.0,
                                             -120).reverse.join('/') %]
```

Testing it with `tpage`:

```
$ tpage days.tt
Original date: 05/12/2023
120 days before: 7/8/2023
```

I've assumed that the date you've mentioned is dd/mm/yyyy. If you're using another, less logical date format then you'll need to adjust the order of the parameters you're passing to `Add_Delta_Days()`.

Comment: Note that you changed the format from having leading zeroes to not having leading zeroes

Comment: @ikegami: Yeah. I like to leave something for the OP to do :-)

Comment: thanks for the response, After reviewing more UserDate values, I am also getting the dates as Jan, 1. 2023 for example. I am trying to find a way to parse the date like strtotime in php and then format it to the desired way to be able to use it in the Add_Delta_Days method.

Comment: @Vidal: Date::Calc also has functions called `Decode_Date_EU()` and `Decode_Date_US()` which might be helpful here.